Skip a page based on Radio Button choice
I am new and didn’t know what NSIS was a few days ago. However, I decided to look into it. I know that similar questions have been asked before, but even reading the answers given by users, I still don’t understand how to go about it.... (Sorry about my English, it’s not my native language.)
Well, the problem is that I want to make an installer. I would like to make a page where a choice is asked to the user through "Radio buttons". The question would be "What do you want to do?"

If the user answers "UDPATE", a directory page will be displayed immediately after.
If the user answers "INSTALLATION", we skip the directory page to go directly to the download.

So, depending on the button the user will click, we should be able to skip the page directory right after.
I tested many things, especially with the PRE, the custom pages. I managed to make the Radio Buttons work (Especially with examples available on the NSIS website) but I can’t skip the directory page after the choice page between INSTALLATION and UPDATE.
I hope everything was clear and thank you in advance for your answers

Just call Abort in the pre-function of the page you want to skip:
RequestExecutionLevel User
InstallDir "$Temp"

!include nsDialogs.nsh

Page Custom MySelectPageCreate MySelectPageLeave
Page Directory DirPagePre
Page License
Page InstFiles

Var IsInUpdateMode

Function MySelectPageCreate
    nsDialogs::Create 1018
    Pop $0

    ${NSD_CreateFirstRadioButton} 8u 30u 80% 10u "&Update"
    Pop $1
    ${NSD_CreateAdditionalRadioButton} 8u 50u 80% 10u "&Install"
    Pop $2
    ${NSD_Check} $1
    ${If} $IsInUpdateMode = 0
        SendMessage $2 ${BM_CLICK} "" ""
    ${EndIf}

    nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function MySelectPageLeave
${NSD_GetState} $1 $IsInUpdateMode
FunctionEnd

Function DirPagePre
${If} $IsInUpdateMode = 0
    Abort
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Section
SectionEnd

